# Change Port for a jersey Web Server

Tags: maven, jersey, jax-ws

I have a Rest Web-server which work fine on local host. I want to deploy it on a server. I got this error

> org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Port number 8080
>   (defined with the property cargo.servlet.port) is in use. Please free
>   it on the system or set it to a different port in the container
>   configuration.

The server is not mine so I can't free the port and must use another one. Is it possible to change to port from the pom.xml? I tried to add this to the pom.xml but it didn't changed anything

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>            
      <configuration>          
        <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
        <port>9966</port>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

But this is for tomcat and I am not even sure that the Web Server is using tomcat. This is the pom.xml of the web-server

```
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

8080 Port use another service. So cargo can not use this port. Therefore you can change ajp and cargo port as follows.

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo.maven2</groupId>
      <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <container>
          <containerId>tomcat5x</containerId>
          [...]
        </container>
        <configuration>
          <properties>
           <cargo.servlet.port>8181</cargo.servlet.port>
           <cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>8012</cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>
          </properties>
        </configuration>
        [...]
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Refer:http://kreskasnotes.blogspot.com/2011/07/problem-with-shutting-down-tomcat-via.html
https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Configuration+properties.html